# Fix element inside scrollable area

Tags: css, html

I just finnished of creating the basis for my chat... I just got around detecting the scroll positioning of the user and want to use this information to make a "Scroll down button" if the chat is not fully scrolled down and a message is recieved. I used position: sticky and that worked all well... But when i got around to testing it across web browsers it did not work very well seems to be very short term to go with it then. What kind of positioning can I use to achieve the same results cross platforms?

```
<div id = 'chatlogs'>
<div class='chatContainer self'>
<div class = 'imgContainer'>
  <img src='displayProfilePicture.php?user_id=$id'>
</div>
<div class='content'>
    <div class = 'message'>
        ". $extract['msg'] ."
    </div>
</div>
```

The chatlogs is filled with multiple of the shown small "chat objects" and no i want for the popup to be placed at the bottom verticaly and center horizontaly in the chatlogs.

```
<span onclick = 'doScroll();' class = 'fa fa-arrow-down'></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: sticky` just works in chrome for now

To make the button fixed in the scroll you need to let him outside the content scrollable

```
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
  <div class="scroll">
    blah blah
  </div>
  <span onclick = 'doScroll();' class = 'fa fa-arrow-down'></span>
</div>
```

and with css you can use position absolute to let it fixed

```
.scroll-wrapper{
  position: relative
}
.fa-arrow-down{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; // center horizontally
  transform: translateX(-50%); // center horizontally
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I tried it out but could not quite seem to get it right. See this jsFiddle and see if you can spot where i went wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/z4ahwg08/13/

Comment: I grouped `chatlogs` and `fa-arrow-down`inside a new div with the class `chat-wrapper` and in css I just set `chat-wrapper` with `position: relative` and `color: #fff`in `fa-arrow-down` https://jsfiddle.net/z4ahwg08/15/

Comment: Thank you very much. I marked your response as correct. Thank you very much for the help.